# SQL Server query MAX and Min

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have been tasked with creating a SQL query (limited knowledge) that will show my max temperature and minimum temperature during the day. The information in the db has timestamps every 20 seconds with the point values. I'd like to just see the max temperature for each day.

I know how to do the MAX and Min:

```
SELECT 
    MIN (pv) As MinimumTemperature
FROM 
    plexxium201.dbo.pv_history

SELECT  
    MAX (pv)
FROM 
    plexxium201.dbo.pv_history
```

I'm just having problems with the date, since there are entries every 20 seconds for a day.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN (pv) As MinimumTemperature, MAX (pv) as MaxTemp, YEAR(datefield) as year, MONTH(datefield) as month, DAY(datefield) as day
FROM plexxium201.dbo.pv_history
GROUP BY YEAR(datefield), MONTH(datefield), DAY(datefield)
```

There is also a way to do this with windowing -- but I think this will serve your needs.

Comment: I'm not sure that would work, my dates are formatted like: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss (all in the same column)

Comment: Is that a datetime column?  If not you can use convert to make a datetime -- if it is a datetime you will be fine.

Comment: It will work fine if it is a datetime column -- don't be afraid -- try it!

Comment: Worked with: SELECT MIN (pv) As MinimumTemperature, MAX (pv) as MaxTemperature, YEAR(pv_ts) as year, MONTH(pv_ts) as month, DAY(pv_ts) as day
FROM plexxium201.dbo.pv_history
GROUP BY YEAR(pv_ts), MONTH(pv_ts), DAY(pv_ts)

Comment: Since the OP is on SQL Server **2008**, you could simplify your group by to `GROUP BY CAST(datefield AS DATE)` - that'll group by day as well

Comment: @marc_s - it is always hard to know when people are doing reports if they want it grouped by day or month, felt this made it clear how it worked.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way of doing this is:

```
select cast(pvh.timestamp as date) as date, min(pv) as mintemp, max(pv) as maxtemp
from plexxium201.dbo.pv_history pvh
group by cast(pvh.timestamp as date)
order by 1
```

I prefer keeping the date field as a date under most circumstances, and SQL Server supports this with the "date" data type.